# Is it possible to delete a field with MongoEngine, without strict=False?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I've got a lot of data in MongoDB, which we access primarily via MongoEngine, and sometimes data first ended up in field F1, and then we later decided that field F2 is a better place for it, so we moved it over there, and stopped using F1.

That's convenient, but now we've got a bunch of stale (or useless) data in old F1 keys, and new documents are being created with empty F1 keys, for no reason.

While MongoDB being schemaless is convenient, I still appreciate the `strict=True` feature (which is on by default), and try to avoid turning it off except when absolutely necessary.  I don't like turning off *all* the safety checks on a collection.

So is there any way to delete a field F1 from my MongoDB collection, without downtime, and without `strict=False`?

- If I remove the field from my Document subclass first, MongoEngine will complain when it tries to load existing documents.
- If I remove the field from my database first, MongoEngine will create it for any new records, until the model is updated.

Is there any way with MongoEngine to say "This is an old field.  You can load it (or ignore it) if it's there, but don't create it for any new documents"?

Comment: So you are basically asking. *"Is it okay to have data that does not strictly conform to our strict schema?"*. MongoDB itself is schemaless and is designed not to care. Once you start employing a software layer that does care, then you are bound to those rules. So your choices here seem to be A. Make the schema rules not care about non-conformant data. B. Alter the data to suit the schema rules. It's a pretty binary solution set.

Comment: Hence if your want to make changes, then use "raw" methods instead to do the manipulation in a way thay does not ask it to conform to the schema. All schema objects have a `.collection` accessor which provides access to the underlying collection object and methods from the core driver.

Comment: First, my question is about MongoEngine, not MongoDB.  Clearly, if I throw schemas out the window entirely, then it's easy.  That was never in question.  Second, your suggestion to use "'raw' methods" sounds like a specific variant of my second bullet point.  Thanks for trying to help, but I know how to do that.  The problem is that (depending on configuration, and ordering) either MongoEngine refuses to load those records, or adds the obsolete fields to any new documents it creates, which defeats the entire purpose.

Comment: I'm looking for how to implement the third solution, "Tell the schema to relax its restriction on this one field".  Every RDBMS ORM I've ever used has had this ability, for example.  It's not outrageous to expect it of a Document-Object Mapper.

Comment: So have you not answered your own question then? The setting is to allow the strict handling to be false if you want to store data that does not comply with the schema. Like I said ( and all I said ) it is a choice between not strict or alter the underlying storage. So I don't really see the point of a question that answers itself, and hence was trying to prompt you for some clarification, and not an argument.

Comment: No, I don't see how "Option A is not what I want, Option B is not what I want, how do I do Option C with this library?  It's a common feature with other similar libraries" is an answer to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I remove the field from my database first, MongoEngine will create it for any new records, until the model is updated

It's only true if you explicitly write to that field or if the field has a default value set. Otherwise the field won't exist in MongoDB.

So as first step I suggest to remove the code that writes to that field and remove the default value (or set it to None). Then it's safe to remove the field from the database.

Below a small proof:

```
import mongoengine

class Foo(mongoengine.Document):
    a = mongoengine.IntField()
    b = mongoengine.ListField(default=None)

f = Foo().save()
type(f.a)  # NoneType
type(f.b)  # NoneType
```

And the database query:

```
> db.foo.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c49ae8ee8b341b4ea02fcb") }
```

Comment: "It's only true if you explicitly write to that field or if the field has a default value set."  Empirically, that is not what happens on my computer.  What version of MongoEngine are you using?

Comment: I'm using `mongoengine==0.10.0`

Comment: Also tested with `mongoengine==0.10.6` with the same result